# Error: [$compile:multidir] when I edit my directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I downloaded [this](https://github.com/legalthings/angular-signature/blob/master/src/signature.js) AngularJS directive, and it works fine, but if I try to change ANY line of code on the directive I recieve the next error:

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [signaturePad, signaturePad] asking for new/isolated scope
```

For some reason, if I edit the directive, the browser detects it like I'm calling 2 different directives (the old version and the new one, i guess).

Any idea about the reason of this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Solved changing the name of the directive... Weird.

Comment: Never edit library source code ... what are you going to do when you need to update it?